# How to access Users in Mongo db console

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm using Mongoid for Ruby. I have queried in my Mongo database before, but forget how it works with Mongo. I have a user model like so:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :email, type String
  field :crypted_password, type String
  ...
end
```

How would I grab all the users or a specific user in my console? Thanks to anyone who can help

Answer (score 1):

```
use *database
```

This returns a specific user:

```
db.getUser("*user")
```

This returns all users

```
db.getUsers()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get a `Error: no such cmd` in my Mongo shell. I figure something like `db.Users.find(email: "foo@bar.com").first` would suffice, but nahh

Answer (score 0):

If your class is called `User` then the underlying MongoDB collection will be `users`. So you'd say things like:

```
> db.users.find() // All users
> db.users.find({ field: value }) // Users that match certain conditions
> db.users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId('...') }) // Find one user with a specific id
...
```

See the [`find`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find) and [`findOne`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/#db.collection.findOne) documentation for further details.

Comment: Snap.. I just did `show dbs` in my Mongo Shell and got two `example_development` databases... one says (empty) and the other is 0.078GB. I did `use example_development` twice... did I screw my database up?

Comment: You shouldn't have two databases with the same name, are you sure you're not missing something in the names?